# How do I search a custom database table (not a wordpress table)?

Tags: database, wordpress, search

I have a pricing table that I have imported into the schema of my wordpress site and now I want to allow the user to search through the table and view it (but not edit it).

**Is there a plugin already** that let's me do this? I found dbtoolkit which is overly complicated and doesn't work in this simple case. I have tried a couple other plugins but they don't seem to work for public users. I want everyone to be able to view and search through the pricing table even if they are not logged in.

I could write my own plugin but I figure why re-invent the wheel if it's already out there.

***Note*: this isn't a standard wordpress table and it has nothing to do with wordpress other than the fact that I imported it into the same database schema. However, I want to use wordpress to search and view this table and show it in a standard wordpress format.

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This is a **SQL/PHP** question, *not* a **WordPress** question. Even if written to be specific to WordPress implementation, the scope of the question would be far too broad to suit the WPSE Q & A format, as it would likely involve: creating custom page templates, sanitizing data, setting up and filtering by query variables, etc.

Comment: I really wish that you didn't move this. This is not a programming question. This is about whether there is a wordpress plugin that does this already so I DON'T HAVE TO WRITE CODE. Not sure how you got the impression that this was a code question.

Comment: Did you find any answer yet? I have the same problem/question. :) Regards